# Kafka consumer disconnect Event

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way we can detect crash or shut down of consumer?
I want that kafka server publish event when mentioned situation to all kafka clients (publishers, consumers....).
Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka keeps track of the consumed offsets per consumer on special internal topics.  You could setup a special "monitoring service", have that constantly consuming from those offset internal topics, and trigger any notification/alerting mechanisms as needed so that your publishers and other consumers are notified programatically.  [This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739443/how-does-zookeeper-retrive-the-consumer-offsets-from-consumer-offsets-topic) has more details about that.

Depending on your use case, lag monitoring is also a really good way to know if your consumers are falling behind and/or crashed.  There's multiple solutions for that out there, or again, you could build your own to customize alerting/notification behavior.